# How to show that extension of linear connection commutes with contraction.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, trace, connections

I am reading John Lee's Riemannian Manifolds, and am having trouble with exercise 4.3.

In order to solve the exercise, you must show that the following definition of a connection on a tensor bundle commutes with contraction.

$(\nabla_X(F))(w^1, ..., w^l, Y_1,...Y_k)=X(F(w^1, ..., w^l, Y_1,...Y_k))-\sum_i F(w^1, ...,\nabla_X w^i,... w^l, Y_1,...Y_k)-\sum_j F(w^1, ..., w^l, Y_1,...,\nabla_X Y_j,...Y_k)$

I was able to prove that the operators commute for tensor bundles in $T^1_1$ but am having trouble for other cases.

How do you prove this for general tensor bundles?

Answer (score 0):

As the tensor $F$ can be locally written as a sum of tensors of the form $Y_1 \otimes  \cdots \otimes Y_{\ell} \otimes \omega^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^k$, we will suppose that
$$ F = Y_1 \otimes  \cdots \otimes Y_{\ell} \otimes \omega^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^k $$
Let us say that we contract the indices $\ell$ and $k$, then
$$ \operatorname{tr} F = \operatorname{tr} (Y_\ell \otimes \omega^k) Y_1 \otimes  \cdots \otimes Y_{\ell-1} \otimes \omega^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{k-1} = \omega^k(Y_\ell) Y_1 \otimes  \cdots \otimes Y_{\ell-1} \otimes \omega^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{k-1} $$
By the product rule (when solving Lee's exercise, you first need to establish the product rule (c) before showing that the connection commutes with contractions), and after some simplifications, we obtain
$$
\operatorname{tr}\nabla_X F - \nabla_X\operatorname{tr} F = \left( \omega^k(\nabla_X Y_\ell) + (\nabla_X \omega^k)(Y_\ell) - X(\omega^k(Y_\ell))\right) Y_1 \otimes  \cdots \otimes Y_{\ell-1} \otimes \omega^1 \otimes \cdots \otimes \omega^{k-1}
$$
which is zero by the definition of $\nabla_X$ for covector fields (formula (i) in Lee's book).